# Response.redirect execute the code inside the pageload twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this link http://localhost:54818/offerslinks/offers.aspx?ID=1  when i clicked it. it loads the page and executes this code twice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL3fF.png)

this code execute twice
can any one help me with that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to share how webform1 is calling the web page that you response.redirect to (maybe the same page???).

You have a isPostBack check, and note that page load ALWAYS will trigger again, and each time for each  button click (post-back) on that given page. So, if you have a simple button on that that webform1, click on it, the page-load event will fire again, and THEN your button code stub will then run.

Of course with a is-postback = false test, then ONLY on first page load should that code run runside that if !PostBack.

However, the code WILL run again if your response.redirect points to the same page.  If you have in that same page, a response.redirect to the SAME page, then not only will page load trigger again, so will the code inside of !IsPostBack code stub.

So, we need more details, or more markup to be posted here (and post the markup in place of screen shots - screen shots are a pain to read, but WORSE is I will often cut + paste markup into a test page while answering questions here - I can't do that if you post image(s), since then I would have to take away time from my life and family, and re-type such markup (or code) to test such things for you when answering questions here.

My best guess is that the response-redirect points to the same page. Thus upon that code running, it re-directs to the same page, and that would thus cause the page load to run again, and also cause isPostBack to be false, which then means the code isside that stub will also run again.

So, missing from this information is how/when/where that page is being loaded - without those details, we are in effect throwing darts in a room with the lights out.

Comment: please note that code execute with these steps :click on the link with query string  then read the parameter in string variable and execute the the code to fetch data from database and sotre the linke in string  variable (each time different link ) and path the link to response redorect(diferent link each time ) when make redirect execute twice

Comment: Are you using a button, or a hyper-link button? Any button you click on will cause the CURRENT page to post-back, and then page.load will trigger. (but then again thats why you have the !IsPostBack code stub. You can use a hyper-link, and that will not cause a post-back, but most if not all buttons on that give pages will FIRST post-back the current page, and the page.load event will and does trigger each time. so it not clear if you have a code behind stub for the hyper-link button, or not.

Comment: remember, if you hyper-link to the SAME page with paramters, then page load triggers, and IsPostBack is ALSO false. this suggests you might want to dump the hyper-link, and use a standard button. however, if you are saying the TARGET navigated page results in the page load triggering two times, then something else on the target page is the issue or problem.  We of course for this discussion assume that the page your are jumping to with the hyper-link button is a DIFFERENT page. as I stated, if the hyper-link points to the current page, then both page.load, and !IsPostback will run each time.

Comment: since your code behind is doing a navagate (with response.redirect), then this suggests you do not want to use a hyper-link on the current page - use a standard button, since code behind is doing the navigation, not the button click. Hyperlink button = I want the client side page to jump to new page - and not run current page code events such as page.load event. So, if that hyper link has a navigation (navagteURL), then you don't want any code stub events attached to that button.

Comment: Please not that I do not use any controls like buttons in this page I  send this link inside email with parameter Id  when any client click the links transfer him to the page and  execute the code in the page load I made break point to the code all code run good but when execute the response .redirect ( different URL ) the code run twice I do not why

Comment: Ok, but we don't know those details. (the fact of creating a instance of that object may well cause it to trigger, and then when you render. The issue of this page being the source of a email is a whopper and a mount Everest of a new detail.  we assume the URL in that routine is different then the current page we are on? Or maybe URL is blank or null - that will also cause a navigate to the same page we are on.